# Issues disabling a button on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm currently having an issue disabling a button on IE.

The issue should be simple to fix... I want a button disabled while a function is running but for some reason on IE the button is never disabled... I've tried two approached both of them work on Chrome and FF but I can't get it to work on IE...

```
document.getElementById('printImage').setAttribute('disabled', true);

document.getElementById('printImage').disabled = true;
```

Additionally if I go on the developer tools on IE and manually set the disabled attribute it does work so I have no idea what's going on.

**UPDATE**

Ok so the issue wasn't on setting the attribute.... the issue is that basically I do this: First I disable the button, then I open a new window using window.open, after that I do so random stuff and finally I do window.focus then window.print() and lastly I do window.close() an after all that I re enable the button but for some reason IE enables it back on even if the new opened window is still open... This works fine in Chrome as it waits for the new window to close before enabling the button again

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Any errors in the console? When are you calling it?

Comment: `<button disabled="" id="printImage">Print</button>` - Disabling a button works fine for me in IE? Are you sure the button actually works after it has been disabled? It looks like a regular button, but it is disabled. http://jsfiddle.net/4z5z8h94/

Comment: Ok so the issue wasn't on setting the attribute.... the issue is that basically I do this. First I disable the button, then I open a new window using window.open, after that I do so random stuff and finally I do window.focus  then window.print() and lastly I do window.close() an after all that I re enable the button but for some reason IE enables it back on even if the new opened window is open... This works fine in Chrome as it waits for the new window to close before enabling the button again

Answer (score 2):

The proper value for a `disabled` attribute is `disabled`. Try:

```
document.getElementById('printImage').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Undo with:

```
document.getElementById('printImage').removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a simple approach like the following will work. I don't have a problem in IE with my solution. What version of IE are you using?

```
document.getElementById("printImage").disabled = true;
```

You can also change the above solution into a reusable function, and even give it a param so you can change the id used in it:

```
function undisableBtn() {
    document.getElementById("printImage").disabled = false;
}
function disableBtn() {
    document.getElementById("printImage").disabled = true;
}
```

Here is a more elaborate approach with a function:

```
// bttnStatus: set to true to disable, and false to enable
function buttonStatus(bttnID,bttnStatus){
    if(bttnStatus == true){
        document.getElementById(bttnID).disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(bttnID).disabled = false;
    }
}

buttonStatus('printImage',true);
```

Comment: He said it's working on Chrome and Firefox, so that's definitely not the issue.